# Using Python and Selenium, how do I find an extjs combobox with xpath?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, extjs, xpath, combobox

The HTML is as follows:

```
<input id="combobox-3829-inputEl" class="x-form-field x-form-text" type="text" style="width: 100%; text-transform: uppercase; -moz-user-select: text;" name="combobox-3829-inputEl" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false" data-errorqtip=""/>
```

I know I need to do something along these lines:

```
//input[starts-with(@id, "combobox-")]
```

but I don't know what to do after that part. The combo box can have the text input in it, I have that part done.  I'm trying to convert everything from absolute XPath to this shorter version. I've figured out buttons and finding text on just fine, but this is my first run in with a combo box. I've searched for as many examples as I can find, but I haven't found a recent one that made it clear for me.

Also, I know the XPath I have defined above can find the combo box, my issue is the page has two combo boxes that are identical in every way except for the generated ID number. How can I index them?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation, I found the best thing for me to do was to index the two comboboxes and then use the send_keys method to input the data into each combobox accordingly. I used something like this:

```
LP_USER_INFO = '//input[starts-with(@id, "combobox-")]'

def set_userInfo(self, data1, data2):
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
        ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, NM.LP_USER_INFO)))
    webComboBox = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, LP_USER_INFO)
    webComboBox[0].send_keys(data1)
    sleep(0.25)
    webComboBox[0].send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    sleep(0.25)
    webComboBox[1].send_keys(data2)
    sleep(0.25)
    webComboBox[1].send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were using STATIC ID's  you could try      `//*[@id='combobox-3829-inputEl']`

// search for all elements `[ * ]` with id of combobox-3829-inputEl `[@id='combobox-3829-inputEl']`

EDIT: It sounds like these ID's are dynamic and generated on page load. Looks like you know the ID always begins with "combo-box-", so your Xpath should suffice

```
//input[starts-with(@id, "combobox-")]
```

For debugging and testing purposes you may want to get some tools in browser to help

- I believe chrome now has it by default
  Inspect > Find Element in "elements tab" > Right Click > Copy > xPath
- Firebug will provide support for FF users

Comment: The point of using XPath is that with ExtJS, the IDs are generated. That number will change each page load. That is why I need to better understand how to manipulate XPath.

Comment: aahh, understood, ok so targeting by ID will not be your best bet. xPath is DOM traversal.. I will update my answer for you

Comment: Yes, I use FireBug, however I guess I should have phrased the question better. Selenium has keywords built in that can be implemented into XPath, such as for a button, you could do:
//div[starts-with(@id, "button-")]//button[. = "Click Me"], however with a combobox, I'm not sure.

Comment: Gotcha, not sure about support for "starts-with".. never used it. still updating answer for ya

Comment: The x-path you posted above looks good to me, try the following URL to test xpaths and see examples http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html